# Maximum Distance in Taxicab Metric on a 2dim Lattice with Periodic boundaries

Tags: geometry

I am looking for the maximum taxicab distance between two points in a 2dim lattice with imposed periodic boundary conditions.

Taxicab Distance in 2 dimensions for two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is defined as:

$|x_1 - x_2| + |y_1 - y_2| $

Let a 2 dimensional lattice be with size $L \times L$ with periodic boundaries such that: $x=L+1=1$ and $y=L+1=1$, so every point is contained within the lattice.

I guess that the maximum distance is $L$, however I am not entirely sure.

$Edit$:

I have added a photo which illustrates the two points where I think the distance between them would be $L$. (The blue point and the blue X) [Points where I think distance might be $L$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVKcy.png)

Comment: If by "periodic" you mean that a point moving off the left edge re-appears on the right edge, then I would think the max distance would be $\lfloor L/2\rfloor,$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i mean. I am thinking about a point at the edge of the square lattice and then another one in the middle of the lattice, so then the distance is $[L/2]$ in $x$ and $[L/2]$ in $y$, so $L$ in total? I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: I have also added a photo illustrating the what I think would be the maximum distance of $L$ in such a setup.

Comment: Oh, right. Yes, I think $L$ would be the max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using periodic boundary conditions on a lattice of this sort, it is helpful to remember that the lattice can, equivalently, just be extended in any direction as far as needed. The arithmetic in a single direction would then be modulo $L,$ so that distance is measured by
$$d((x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2))=((x_2-x_1)(\!\!\!\!\!\!\mod L))+((y_2-y_1)(\!\!\!\!\!\!\mod L)). $$
Plugging in a few points in the image included in the question will convince you that this is correct.

So, taking a single direction under consideration, we see that the maximum distance obtainable in just the $x$ direction would have to be $\lfloor L/2\rfloor,$ where the floor function is necessary to handle division by an odd $L.$ The same is true in the $y$ direction, which makes the maximum distance
$$d_{\max}=2\left\lfloor\frac{L}{2}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer!